Legendre transformation is a continuous map 2
I was reading an article about the Legendre Transformation in Convex Analysis.
It was defined like this:

Let $\varphi$ be a  continuous function on $\left[0,\infty\right)$ and convex on $\mathbb{R}_{> 0}$, we defined the function $\varphi^{*}$ on $\left[0,\infty\right)$ as :
$$
\forall\ \lambda \in \left[0,\infty\right),\quad
\varphi^{*}\left(\lambda\right) := \inf_{x\ \in\ \left[0,\infty\right)}\left[\lambda x + \varphi\left(x\right) - \varphi\left(0\right)\right]
$$
$\varphi^{*}$ is so called the Legendre Transform of the function $\varphi$.

The map $\varphi^{*}$ is concav on $\left[0,\infty\right)$ si it is continue on the open intervall $\left]0,\infty\right)$.
How could we extend this result to say that $\varphi^{*}$ is continuous at the extremities of this interval?

Since $x\ge 0$ the limit of $\lambda x+\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)$ for $\lambda\downarrow 0$ is the infimum. Since we can exchange $\inf\limits_{x\in[0,\infty)}$ and $\inf\limits_{\lambda\in[0,\infty)}$ we should be done.
